# Agregar firma digital Base64 a un pdf en Java/AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firma-digital

he descargado un SDK del ministerio del interior para leer por NFC la firma digital de un DNI (https://www.dnielectronico.es/PortalDNIe/PRF1_Cons02.action?pag=REF_036&id_menu=21).

Funciona perfectamente y obtengo mi firma digital X509 en Base64. Ahora bien necesito saber cómo aplicar esa firma digital a un pdf, llevo horas deambulando y no logro encontrar el modo.

```
final PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(certificateBean.getAlias(), null);
final X509Certificate[] certificateChain = (X509Certificate[]) keyStore.getCertificateChain(certificateBean.getAlias());

        _executor.execute(()->{
            final String result = doInBackground(privateKey, certificateChain);
            _handler.post(() -> {
                updateInfo(result==null?"Firma realizada.":"Error en proceso de firma.",
                        result==null?Base64.encodeToString(_signature, Base64.DEFAULT):result);
            });
        });
```

Una vez obtenida y verificada en el método "doInBackground()" la firma la codifico (Quizá se deba integrar al pdf en este formato antes de pasarlo a Base64, lo desconozco. El código del SDK lo pasa a Base64 por defecto)

Tengo la firma pero no puedo integrarla en el pdf :'). Gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido, cuál es el código?, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, por favor. Revisar [ask], saludos.